Git blame in 2 branches shows same commit as responsible for 2 different values
I used two git blame views in Gitlab to show the history of a file in two different branches.
For a specific line, the last change points to the same commit in both branches.
The thing is: the lines content is not the same.
If I review the commit it points me to, I can see that the change produced the line like in one of the branches, but not the other.
Update: The git blame output on my local machine shows a different commit for the same line. So this seems to be limited to the blame view of Gitlab. It might be a bug and not suited for StackOverflow then, but I'll change the tags to include gitlab and wait a bit if someone can confirm.
I haven't yet identified where in the history the change to the other content happened (could maybe use bisect), but my question is rather: how can this happen? What possible interaction with git could have caused this? Has it something to do with merge conflict resolutions that introduce a manual third option instead of taking over content from either of the 2 branches? (But then the merge should show up as last change in the blame view)
